# R: reading geotiff data straight from web url (httr::GET raw content)

Tags: r, raster, httr, rgdal, geotiff

I would like to create a RasterLayer from GeoTIFF data provided by a server. I'll query the server for this data using a httr::GET call (the data is provided on-demand, so in the application there won't be a url ending in .tif but a query url).

After writing the result of this call to disk as a GeoTIFF file it's easy enough to create the RasterLayer from the resulting GeoTIFF file on disk:

```
library(httr)
library(raster)

url <- 'http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/cea.tif'

geotiff_file <- tempfile(fileext='.tif')
httr::GET(url,httr::write_disk(path=geotiff_file))
my_raster <- raster(geotiff_file)
my_raster
```

However, I would like to skip the write to disk part and create the raster straight from the in-memory server response.

```
response <- httr::GET(url,httr::write_memory())
response
```

The content of the response is a raw string which I would need to interpret as geoTIFF data.

```
str(httr::content(response))
```

However, I can only find raster or rgdal functions to read from a file. Any suggestions on translating this raw string to a raster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GDAL has some cool [virtual file system driver](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html), one of which is `/vsicurl` that

> allows on-the-fly random reading of files available through HTTP/FTP web protocols, without prior download of the entire file. It requires GDAL to be built against libcurl.

Since the `raster` package builds on `rgdal` you can simply do this:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster('/vsicurl/http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/cea.tif')

plot(r)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me on windows. Perhaps because the windows rgdal was not built with libcurl?

Comment: @RobertHijmans Haven't tested it on windows - works on Linux. Could be either an issue with libcurl or the gdal version. Do the other virtual file systems work for you?

Comment: Works on Linux, but on Windows the raster() line gives an error: Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Comment: I tried with a path to a file on disk, but that gives the same error. Not sure how to check whether other virtual file systems work.

Comment: @WillemMaetens You could try `/vsizip' which can read images from a `.zip` archive on disk. If that works, it's probably an issue with libcurl. Another option would be trying python GDAL, to see if it's an issue with `rgdal`

Comment: I tried a couple of things on Windows. First off, gdal.Open("/vsicurl/http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/cea.tif") does work in python. In R, gdalinfo() from package gdalUtils (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/versions/2.0.1.14/topics/gdalinfo) on the url works: gdalUtils::gdalinfo('/vsicurl/http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/cea.tif'). Similarly /vsizip on a zip file works with gdalUtils::gdalinfo(), but not with raster(). Seems to point to how the paths are handled by the raster function, strange thing is that it's specific for windows.

Comment: @WillemMaetens nicely tested. Looks like the issue is with `rgdal`, either with the gdal version or with the libcurl functionality.

Comment: A workaround on windows is to build a vrt 1st (QGIS has this same issue) ```
library(gdalUtils)
gdalbuildvrt('/vsicurl/http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/cea.tif','cea.vrt')
r <- raster('cea.vrt')
```