# R: Is there a way I can read raster tif file from google cloud storage without saving to file?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, r-raster

I have a set of raster geotif files in a bucket in google cloud storage that I would like to read and use in a web platform (like shiny).

To connect and download the data I am using googleCloudStorageR library and to display the raster I am using raster library.

Below is an example of the code to download a tif and then read it with raster library as any regular tif file which works fine.

```
library(googleCloudStorageR)
library(raster)
...authenthication and set bucket of interest (data omitted)...
#Download to a tif file and plot
download <- gcs_get_object(objects$name[[post]], bucket=bucket, saveToDisk = filegeo1.tif,    overwrite = TRUE)
r1<-raster(filegeo1.tif)
plot(r1)
```

However, what I want is to able to read into memory the data and plot without saving into a tif file locally.

```
#Download to raw in memory 
raw_raster <- gcs_get_object(objects$name[[post]], bucket=bucket, saveToDisk = NULL)
str(raw_raster)
raw_raster
saveRDS(raw_raster, file = "raw_raster_from_googlecloudstorage.Rds")
```

The result of the above commands can be seen like:
[Screenshot of console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akIRM.png)

I saved the file as Rds so anyone can have a use it for testing purposes in this [open link to download file in mega storage](https://mega.nz/file/GcsyAALL#wFOXHlxQLp2okQsYdTQYgO2f7qP3Hs2O61FGkDKtxPo). If I could transform from this raw data to geotif it would be great and would solve my situation.

I have read other question reported about [reading geotiff data straight from web URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182635/r-reading-geotiff-data-straight-from-web-url-httrget-raw-content) but is not the same since I don't have an url for each file.
So what advice can you provide? I appreciate the help.
Thank you,

Comment: If you have the URL to the file on the cloud, why don't you pass the URL to raster? You might check ?connections,, especially url and pipe connections.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Eyayaw! The thing is that the URL has not public access so when I use for example: rurl <- raster('/vsicurl/https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/raster/gndvi/10_jkm_3871.tif')  I get a 403 error message with access denied. How can overcome this?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754764